# VBA Excel run some parts of the code only once when using command buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a few pieces of my code, and some of them I want to use only once.
Here are the pieces of my code:

```
Sub Divider()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim Shp As Shape

   Set ws = ActiveSheet

   Sheets("Cables 1").Shapes("Divider1").Copy
   ws.Range("B25").PasteSpecial
   Selection.Name = "Divider"

   Set Shp = ws.Shapes("Divider")
   Location Shp, Range("b25:L50")
   End Sub

   Sub CivBox()
    With ActiveSheet
    .Shapes("Civils 3").Copy
    [C26].Activate
    .Paste
    .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Name = "Civils 4"
    .Shapes("Civils 4").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "4"
    End With
  End Sub
```

and also

```
 Public Sub ResizeCiv2()

  Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
  Dim targetRange As Range
  Dim targetShape As Shape


   ' Define the sheet that has the pictures
   Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  ' Define the range the images is going to fit
   Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("C3:K24")

  ' Loop through each Shape in Sheet
   For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes
    ' Check "picture" word in name
     If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
        ' Call the resize function
        SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange
    End If

Next targetShape

Call CivBox
Call Divider

ActiveSheet.Range("M15").Value = Range("D52")
Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(50, 3).Value = Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(50, 3).Value + 1
Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(51, 3).Value = Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(51, 3).Value + 1

End sub
```

From the following code I want to run the section below only once using the form control button.

```
Call CivBox
Call Divider

ActiveSheet.Range("M15").Value = Range("D52")
Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(50, 3).Value = Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(50, 3).Value + 1
Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(51, 3).Value = Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(51, 3).Value + 1
```

[image]

Is there a chance to accomplish it?

Comment: Accomplish what? Your problem is not clear (to me at least).

Comment: Can confirm not clear at all

Comment: I want to have the stuff removed, which is marked red. I want to have it populated only once, and next block the part of the code (use it only once) when clicking the button.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break on some code line and then stepping thru to see how the multiple times happens?

Comment: It happens as much times as I click on the button. I must think about some if statement, which will prevent me from creation the object several times.