# VBA Excel if statement for odd & even values

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set the IF statement for odd & even values in VBA Excel.

This is an idea, which I got after this query here:

[VBA Excel run some parts of the code only once when using command buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60955007/vba-excel-run-some-parts-of-the-code-only-once-when-using-command-buttons)

My code is related to another part of the code above and looks as follows:

```
 Public Sub ResizeCiv2()
   ' image autoresize code
   Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
   Dim targetRange As Range
   Dim targetShape As Shape


  ' Define the sheet that has the pictures
   Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   ' Define the range the images is going to fit
   Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("C3:K24")


   ' Loop through each Shape in Sheet
    For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes
    ' Check "picture" word in name
    If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
        ' Call the resize function
        SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange
    End If

   Next targetShape

   'elements + numeration code

   Dim odd, even As Range
   Set even = ActiveSheet.Range("C51")
   Set odd = ActiveSheet.Range("C52")

   If even.Value = "TRUE" Then
   Call CivBox
   Call Divider
   ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 4).Value + 1
   End If
   If odd.Value = "FALSE" Then
   ActiveSheet.Cells(52, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(52, 4).Value + 1
   ActiveSheet.Range("M15").Value = Range("D52")
   End If

  End Sub
```

No error, but no reaction at all.
I want to have this condition working.
[image]

Basically I set the **ISEVEN** function for adjacent columns (C51 and C52), which in relation accordingly to D51 and D52 returns TRUE or FALSE. I would like to use this value in my IF statement. I don't understand why doesn't it work? Shall I write the VBA code for odd & even values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `False`:

```
If Even.Value = "TRUE" Then
If Odd.Value = "FALSE" Then
```

*This* is `True`:

```
If Even.Value = True Then
If Odd.Value = False Then
```

And **this** is simpler:

```
If Even.Value Then
If Not Odd.Value Then
```

You are trying to compare a `Boolean` with a `String`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, the IF condition is not running because the condition you set is a String ("TRUE" and "FALSE"), while it's in fact a Boolean in Excel.

You should use the following:

```
If even.Value = True Then
...
End If
```

Boolean are recognized in VBA. So no need to use "TRUE" or "FALSE", but simply True or False.